Is the character group defined in $\mathbb{C}^*$ or $\mathbb{S}^1$?
I have beeen searching for the definition of the character group and depending where you read it, you may find one choice or another.
Let $G$ be a group. A character (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics]) is a homomorphism $\xi:G\to A$, where $A$ is some abelian group. We denote $\widehat{G}:=\operatorname{Hom}(G,A)$ which is a group with the component-wise product.
The following choices for $A$ appear frequently when defining the character group (see [Wikipedia]): $A=\mathbb{C}^*$ or $A=\mathbb{S}^1$. In particular, I have seen $\mathbb{S}^1$ much more because of its interest in topological groups and the Pontryagin duality.
I understand that if $G$ is a torsion group, there is no difference between $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$, since $\forall x\in G$, $x^n=e$ and $1=\xi(e)=\xi(x^n)=\xi(x)^n$, wich implies that $|\xi(x)|=1$. However, when $G$ is not a torsion group, is there a difference between $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$? Also, is there a prefered choice as the stardad definition—if there is such thing as "standard" in this context?

It depends on the context: sometimes it is neither and instead one uses $GL_1(F)=F^\times$, where $F$ is whatever field one is working with. Sometimes one even uses additive characters, not multiplicative ones.

What difference do you mean when you write ‘However, when there is not a torsion group, is there a difference between $\mathbb{C}^$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$?’ Are we talking about abstract groups $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{C}^)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{S}^1)$ or topological groups?
